# Is there an Xcode 4.2 for Snow Leopard?

Tags: osx-snow-leopard, xcode, ios

I was looking for Xcode 4.2 for Snow Leopard.

I had heard that the official release for iOS 5 was also going to be Snow Leopard enabled.

I could not find Xcode 4.2 + iOS5 for Snow Leopard on Apple's Dev site. Is there a known discussion on this?

Comment: Pinging @slhck -- See the answer

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, if you log into the Dev Center, right below **Xcode 4.2 for Lion** is **Xcode 4.2 for Snow Leopard**. Unlike the one for Lion, which takes you to the App Store, it's a plain old 1.76 GB .dmg, and includes the iOS 5 SDK.

Edit: here is a [direct link](https://developer.apple.com/devcenter/download.action?path=/Developer_Tools/xcode_4.2_with_ios_5_sdk/xcode_4.2_and_ios_5_sdk_for_snow_leopard.dmg), which still requires authorization.

Comment: Where? [This is](http://i.stack.imgur.com/ugi8n.png) what I see.

Comment: That looks like the old page. The "Looking for Xcode 3" link is under the new 4.2 for Snow Leopard section. Slightly different on the Mac vs. iOS Dev Centers, but quite plain on both. Try logging into the other one.

Comment: Obviously I'm still being served the old page? Did [a quick screencast](http://screencast.com/t/5b7Up4GKF) to make sure we're referring to the same.

Comment: Ken, I dont see it. I see exactly what slhck has. I was told in passing that Xcode 4.2 was for Snow Leopard as well but I can't find it

Comment: Try logging out and then back in with the **Log in** button at the top.

Comment: not seeing it, can you post a direct link to the Xcode 4.2 for Snow Leopard download?

Comment: Link added to answer

Comment: Still getting an "Access Denied", although I'm logged in. It's [just not there](http://i.stack.imgur.com/QvgUP.png). Maybe I'll give it a couple of days. /cc @RD.

Comment: I'm getting at Access Denied, but I googled the file name (thanks!) and the first link contains a download :)  cheers

Comment: *Cough* http://tpb.pirateparty.org.uk/torrent/7269465/Xcode_4.2_for_Snow_Leopard_-_Apple_Developer_Center

Comment: Ken's link is out of date. The current link is: [Xcode 4.2 for Snow Leopard](http://adcdownload.apple.com/Developer_Tools/xcode_4.2_for_snow_leopard/xcode_4.2_for_snow_leopard.dmg). Current as of May 5 2013.

Answer (score 6):

Go to http://imzdl.com/download/397/torrent/xcode4.2ios5sdksnowleopard.torrent to download Xcode 4.2 for Snow Leopard or use the following magnet link.

```
magnet:?xt=urn:btih:db3128479b334db88c4c048e9257387afbed7f39&dn=Xcode+4.2+for+Sn‌​ow+Leopard+-+Apple+Developer+Center&tr=udp%3A%2F%2Ftracker.openbittorrent.com%3A8‌​0&tr=udp%3A%2F%2Ftracker.publicbt.com%3A80&tr=udp%3A%2F%2Ftracker.istole.it%3A696‌​9&tr=udp%3A%2F%2Ftracker.ccc.de%3A80
```

Comment: Thanks for this, I can't believe how difficult Apple make this, there's pushing upgrades to Lion but this is crazy, I only need an updated version of Xcode because Homebrew said install 3.2.6 (which I can't find anywhere either! Apple's download link just stalled on me)

Comment: I crossed my fingers and upgraded to Lion. so far so good

Comment: @GregK: 3.2.6 for Snow Leopard is still available from https://developer.apple.com/downloads (type "xcode 3" in the search box). Or directly: http://adcdownload.apple.com/Developer_Tools/xcode_3.2.6_and_ios_sdk_4.3__final/xcode_3.2.6_and_ios_sdk_4.3.dmg

Comment: @marcin: Requires authentication sadly. Also the imzdl link doesn't work, however I found it on TPB: magnet:?xt=urn:btih:db3128479b334db88c4c048e9257387afbed7f39&dn=Xcode+4.2+for+Snow+Leopard+-+Apple+Developer+Center&tr=udp%3A%2F%2Ftracker.openbittorrent.com%3A80&tr=udp%3A%2F%2Ftracker.publicbt.com%3A80&tr=udp%3A%2F%2Ftracker.istole.it%3A6969&tr=udp%3A%2F%2Ftracker.ccc.de%3A80

Answer (score 2):

Yes there is a xcode4.2 for snow leopard, however it only appeared after signing up to the iOS development program for me.

Comment: Can you inform the size and md5sum of this file Dominic?
It is difficult to tell if files over the web is authentic.